# why my http redirect don't work with nagios?

Tags: https, httpd.conf

I have a webserver with nagios, nagios is the only service working in this vm, so I want when I go to the root https://mymachine to redirect directly to https://mymachine/nagios.
I have made a configuration like this

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName mymachine.mydomain
   ServerAdmin root@mymachine.mydomain
   Redirect / https://mymachine.mydomain/nagios
   # SSL Engine Switch:
   # Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/nagios1.mymachine.mydomain.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/nagios1mymachine.mydomain.key
   SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mymachine.mydomain.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart http and..disaster! Firefox open the page

```
https://nagios1.mymachine.mydomain/nagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagiosnagios
```

and give the "redirect loop" error.
Consider I have also a redirect from http to https
active

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

If I remove it is the same thing.
Any solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName nagios1.mymachine.mydomain
   ServerAdmin root@mymachine.mydomain
   Redirect "/" "https://nagios1.mymachine.mydomain/nagios"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
      # SSL Engine Switch:
   # Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/nagios1.mymachine.mydomain.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/nagios1mymachine.mydomain.key
   SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mymachine.mydomain.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution, it’s a great thing to do. I would just like to point out that this is an Apache issue and not a Nagios issue, so you should consider changing the tags for the question as such.